# Setting make variable inside target

Tags: linux, compilation, gnu-make

Given GNU Make 3.81.

The below makefile

```
all:
        echo before
TEST=1
        echo after
```

yields "commands commence before first target.  Stop." on "TEST=1" line.

From other side adding "override" to TEST as following:

```
all:
        echo before
override TEST=1
        echo after
```

runs fine (both before and "after" are "printed").

Questions:

1. Why "TEST=1" is not ok, while "override TEST=1" is ok?
2. Why "override TEST=1" inside target's command is fine? Proba

Comment: Similar to [Conditionally appending to a variable inside a Makefile target](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2148892/2509).

Comment: @dmckee Target-specific variables defined in prerequisite part of rule, while TEST variable is somewhere in command part of rule.

Comment: There is a reason my comment does not say "duplicate".

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that

```
override TEST=1
```

gets interpreted as:

```
override: TEST=1
```

... which is perfectly valid in GNU make.

You can modify variables per-target simply by naming the target and then setting the variable as you would in the global section of the make file, such as this:

```
<target>: <variable>:=<value>
<target>: <variable>=<value>
<target>: <variable>+=<value>
```

This way it is common-place to append something to or modify `CFLAGS` for just a single object file ...

*NOTE:* **However**, it is wrong syntax to make a variable assignment within the command-block of a target as you were trying.

Comment: `target: A:=1` definitely doesn't work (fails with `/bin/sh: 1: A:=: not found`) and `target A=1` causes `A` to be empty when used with `$(A)`.

Comment: @KarlRichter: `target: A:=1` is GNU make specific. I have **no** idea how or why `/bin/sh` would get involved there. After all this is *not* inside a recipe. And `target A=1` still requires a colon (`:`) behind `target`, because the intention is to limit the variable assignment to a single target (which can be a file or a phony target). And yes, this definitely works. Did you actually read the *NOTE* at the end of my answer?! Because your comment strongly suggests that you're falling prey to the same fallacy as the OP of the question.