# Multi-use Makefiles?

Tags: makefile

I have the files `main.c`, `version1.c`, `version2.c` and `header.h`

`version1.c` and `version2.c` are two different implementations of the same header file (`header.h`), and this header file is used by `main.c`.

Now, I want to

```
$ make v1
cc -c main.c
cc -c version1.c
cc -o prog main.o version1.o
```

or

```
$ make v2
cc -c main.c
cc -c version2.c
cc -o prog main.o version2.o
```

depending on which version of code I'm using.

I tried [Conditionally appending to a variable inside a Makefile target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148892/conditionally-appending-to-a-variable-inside-a-makefile-target) and wrote

```
.PHONY: v1 v2
OBJ = main.o
v1: OBJ += version1.o
v2: OBJ += version2.o
v1 v2: prog
prog: $(OBJ)
     cc -o prog $(OBJ)
%.o: %.c header.h
     cc -c $<
```

But this quite simply does not work:

```
$ make v1
cc -c main.c
cc -o prog main.o version1.o
cc: version1.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [prog] Error 1
```

it seems that `make` evaluates `$(OBJ)` *before* the append when it appears in the dependency list, but *after* it when it appears in the command list.

Is this a bug in `make`? Or am I just doing it wrong? How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target-specific modification of the variable (`v1: OBJ += version1.o`) applies in the body of the rule, not in the prerequisite list. Here's how I'd do it:

```
.PHONY: v1 v2
v1: version1.o
v2: version2.o
v1 v2: main.o
    cc -o prog $^

%.o: %.c header.h
    cc -c $<
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly!

I would have expected that $^ would have expanded to only main.o, I guess I've learnt lots of new things today!

Thank you once again!